# After migrating site from xampp to IIS, Curl is not saving the contents of cookiefile, but is able to generate the file

Tags: php, curl, iis

I searched for this on google but all the links refer to curl not being able to save the file, but on my case is diferent, curl is saving the file correctly but the contents are only as you can see:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

--- no cookie contents here ---- only header ----
```

I have this website running in Xampp and everything works. 
when I migrated to IIS, the only problem that I have is curl not saving the contents of cookies in the file.

I have no clue what i did wrong.

```
//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);
//The JSON data.
$jsonData = array(
    'login' =>  $login,
    'password' =>  $password,
    'idioma' =>  $idioma,
    'server' =>  $server,
    'sistema' =>  $sistema
);


//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "C:\cookies\cookieFile.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "C:\cookies\cookieFile.txt");


//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);


//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 


//Execute the request
$data=curl_exec($ch);

if ($data) {
//var_dump($data);



}else
{
    echo "Não foi possível abrir o Sistema no Serviço Eticadata";
}
curl_close($ch);
```

To make sure I am recieving header cookies I added this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

This is in the response when I var_dump Data

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Pragma: no-cache Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ke2s2lf0mkdbqlcfbghrqgg5; path=/; HttpOnly X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 Set-Cookie: .eti_ASPXAUTH=5DE2B541B7CCE00C4356B3D0D9CA0D82C9819A5EB9E915924913DCB3B7FB511D6A27026CECC878FD295B1E8F262B53A8A9F9946318BEEE4C0487ED9F9B64547451EDC9D2C4458A8FEECFEABBD24EE0CF2DD2FCD80B4C3931622309DB443E35066A71B8C01A160F4DDA5FE8594E4C7DD6E62B2D55EB25FCCC9C1C7F304F3285E0; path=/; HttpOnly Set-Cookie: eti_sessionInfo=YwBzAHcAcwBxAGwAXABjAG8AbQBwAHUAcwCnAFMAaQBzAHQAZQBtAGEAQwBTAFcApwBDAFMAVwCnAEUAeAAgADIAMAAxADkApwAxAKcAUABUAC0AUABUAA==; path=/ X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2019 15:27:01 GMT Content-Length: 56350
```

But looking at C:\cookies\cookieFile.txt its contents are:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.
```

And no cookies inside.

Edit

Heres the verbose of curl

```
* upload completely sent off: 106 out of 106 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Expires: -1
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
* cookie 'ASP.NET_SessionId' dropped, domain 'cswsql' must not set cookies for 'cswsql'
< Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=khdalre2kjro4usbaq4co33c; path=/; HttpOnly
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
* cookie '.eti_ASPXAUTH' dropped, domain 'cswsql' must not set cookies for 'cswsql'
< Set-Cookie: .eti_ASPXAUTH=75524EDA1707527A449A395913EDB222D37F40171D44037CA430958BD2F24BF90C2975461F57F58EC6A6E0450ACD98AE64092B13CCDAA73E4CE7207AA2CE834688CBD4113C82AFAB4F513FC2DEFFCEF34496FF47896BCF8BBB3424FD6F6F8F1593B7869E2647AEB82F9D6CD89B2E939E38036D4A94635072996E88528225E793; path=/; HttpOnly
* cookie 'eti_sessionInfo' dropped, domain 'cswsql' must not set cookies for 'cswsql'
< Set-Cookie: eti_sessionInfo=YwBzAHcAcwBxAGwAXABjAG8AbQBwAHUAcwCnAFMAaQBzAHQAZQBtAGEAQwBTAFcApwBDAFMAVwCnAEUAeAAgADIAMAAxADkApwAxAKcAUABUAC0AUABUAA==; path=/
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Thu, 13 Jun 2019 14:09:21 GMT
< Content-Length: 56350
< 
* Connection #0 to host cswsql left intact
```

Comment: Searches that I did on google: COOKIEJAR generates file but does not save any contents int it;
COOKIEJAR file contents is empty

Comment: You're not showing us any code. We can't help you!

Comment: @DanielStenberg I added the code, do you know what am I doing wrong?